# Signature/date line with fixed width

Tags: spacing, boxes, rules

I'm trying to create a signature and date line in a document.  I need the date line to always be in the same spot on the page no matter what name is under the signature line, such as:

```
----------------------   ----------------------
Representative           Date

----------------------   ----------------------
Program Manager          Date
```

Here is the code I currently have:

```
\makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill} \hspace {1.0in}\makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill} \\
User Representative \makebox[2.5in][r]{Date} \\

\vspace{.2in}
\makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill} \hspace {1.0in}\makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill} \\
Program Manager \makebox[2.5in][r]{Date} \
```

I want to be able to change the names, such as change Program Manager to Joe Foo and have the word 'Date' stay in the exact place.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm still a newbie at TeX so please forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 32):

You can use `\makebox` to set the text in a fixed amount of space.  Below I have defined a `SignatureAndDate` macro to make this easier to use:

[image]

I used the `showframe` package to show the margins so you can see the placement relative to that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\newcommand*{\SignatureAndDate}[1]{%
    \par\noindent\makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill} \hfill\makebox[2.0in]{\hrulefill}%
    \par\noindent\makebox[2.5in][l]{#1}      \hfill\makebox[2.0in][l]{Date}%
}%
\begin{document}
\SignatureAndDate{User Representative}
\vspace{.2in}
\SignatureAndDate{Program Manager}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding `\usepackage{showframe}` caused all text fields to be outlined in black for me? However, this command doesn't seem to be necessary and it can be removed.

Comment: @MRule: That to me indicates something else went wrong. To debug it, first check that the MWE given here works. If it does then, some other package or setting that you are using is the cause. I suggest poosting a question with a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.  Including the output of `\listfiles` will help to figure out which package is the cause.

Answer (score 29):

I'd use a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{ll}
\makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill} & \makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill}\\
User Representative & Date\\[8ex]% adds space between the two sets of signatures
\makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill} & \makebox[2.5in]{\hrulefill}\\
Program Manager & Date\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: the output]

For details on `tabular`s, I recommend section 2.11.6 of [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf).

Comment: Can I use dotted line instead?

Comment: @xxx--- Using `\dotfill` instead of `\hrulefill` seems to work.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the following command `\titledate[<width>]{<title>}` to draw your "title and date" configurations. Each are set it a `tabular` of width `<width>` (default is `2.5in`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\titledate}[2][2.5in]{%
  \noindent%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{#1}@{}}
    \\ \hline \\[-.75\normalbaselineskip]
    #2
  \end{tabular} \hspace{1in}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{#1}@{}}
    \\ \hline \\[-.75\normalbaselineskip]
    Date
  \end{tabular}
}
\begin{document}

\titledate{User Representative}

\titledate{Program Manager}

\titledate[2in]{My title}

\end{document}
```

Modifying the width parameter adjusts both sides to the new `<width>`.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following macros `\signatureline` and `signaturedash` for this. These allow me to set the line parameters quite flexibly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
  \newcommand*\signaturelinewidth{5cm}
  \newcommand*\signaturelineheight{.4pt}
  \newcommand*\signaturedashleaderatom{\kern .1pt.\kern .1pt}
  \newcommand*\signaturelineraise{.4ex}
  \newcommand*\signaturelabelindent{.5cm}
  \newcommand*\signaturetextindent{}
  \NewDocumentCommand\signatureline{
    O{\signaturelinewidth}      % line width
    O{\signaturelabelindent}    % label margin
    O{%                           text indentation
      \ifx\@empty\signaturetextindent
        .5\dimexpr #2\relax
      \else
        \signaturetextindent
      \fi
    }
    m                           % label
    O{\signaturelineheight}     % line height
    O{\signaturelineraise}      % line raise
    D||{}                       % text
  }{%
    \parbox[t]{#1}{%
      \leftskip #3%
      \mbox{\strut #7}%
      \vskip -#6%
      \hrule height #5%
      \vskip #6%
      \scriptsize
      \leftskip #2%
      \rightskip #2%
      \strut #4%
    }%
  }
  \NewDocumentCommand\signaturedash{
    O{\signaturelinewidth}      % line width
    O{\signaturelabelindent}    % label margin
    O{%                           text indentation
      \ifx\@empty\signaturetextindent
        .5\dimexpr #2\relax
      \else
        \signaturetextindent
      \fi
    }
    m                           % label
    O{\signaturedashleaderatom} % leader atom
    O{\signaturelineraise}      % line raise
    D||{}                       % text
  }{%
    \parbox[t]{#1}{%
      \leftskip #3%
      \mbox{\strut #7}%
      \vskip -#6%
      \leftskip 0pt%
      \hrule height 0pt%
      \leavevmode\cleaders\hbox{#5}\hfill\kern 0pt%
      \hrule height 0pt%
      \vskip #6%
      \scriptsize
      \leftskip #2%
      \rightskip #2%
      \strut #4%
    }%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}\makeatletter

Sign here:
\signatureline[3cm]{Date}|\today|
\signatureline[6cm]{Pat McDaniel\\Program Manager}

Sign here:
\signaturedash[3cm]{Date}|\today|
\signaturedash[6cm]{Pat McDaniel\\Program Manager}

Sign here:
\signaturedash[3cm]{\centering Date}[\kern 1pt\rule{.5em}{1ex}\kern 1pt]|\today|
\signaturedash[6cm]{\centering Pat McDaniel\\Program Manager}[\kern 1pt\rule{1em}{1ex}\kern 1pt]

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Looks a little complicated!

Comment: @xxx--- Well, more functionality requires more complex macros. If you don't need this functionality, a different solution may be enough for you. (You could of course reduce this one, but I don't see the point of that.)

Answer (score 0):

Slightly improving [David Carlisle's Answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48155/218552) so that you only need to specify the width in the `tabular` header

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{p{2.5in}p{2.5in}}
    \hrulefill          & \hrulefill \\
    User Representative & Date       \\[8ex]% adds space between the two sets of signatures
    \hrulefill          & \hrulefill \\
    Program Manager     & Date       \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```