# Full page table template

Tags: tables, blank-page, forms

I am making a manual with LaTeX and at the end of the manual I want to insert a full-page blank table where I can have people sign to acknowledge that they have read the manual.

Currently I am doing this:

```
\section{Sign on sheet}
% NOTE: This is a very messy way of making a one page table.
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|+l|^X|^l|^X|}

\hline
\rowstyle{\bfseries}
Date & Name & Signature \\\hline\hline
1 January 2012 & John Citizen & XXXXXXXXX \\\hline
& & \\[0.4cm]\hline
& & \\[0.4cm]\hline
...
& & \\[0.4cm]\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

And I have to play around with the number of lines to make it fill the page. I use `\\[0.4cm]` to make the rows a little larger to leave space for handwriting when the document is printed. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Related: [dynamic signature/date line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48152/dynamic-signature-date-line), or is this a duplicate?  Since your page size is not going to change often, you could just manually repeat one of the linked solutions to fill the page.

Comment: Here's a way to avoid having to input all those `[0.4cm]` extra-space specifiers: Load the `array` package in the preamble and issue the command `\setlength\extrarowheight{0.4cm}`. If you issue the latter command in the preamble it'll affect all tabular environment; to keep its scope local to just one `tabularx` environment, issue the command after an opening curly brace (`{`) and before the `\begin{tabularx}{...` statement, and issue a closing curly brace (`}`) after the end of the `tabularx` environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest a different approach, not using a tabular structure; the `\linefill` command in the example below is a modification of the same command from the [exam](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam) document class; it fills the vertical space of height given as its argument with the pattern of horizontal lines declared by `\linefill`. You use a minipage with fixed height `h` for the header and then you symply use `\linefill{\textheight-h}` to fill the page with the pattern; the vertical separation between lines can be changed by using the length `\linefillheight` (initially set to `1cm`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\linefillheight % vertical distance between lines
\setlength\linefillheight{1cm}

\newlength\wcolone %first column width
\setlength\wcolone{\dimexpr.25\textwidth-4mm\relax}
\newlength\wcoltwo %second column width
\setlength\wcoltwo{.5\textwidth}
\newlength\wcolthree % third column width
\setlength\wcolthree{\dimexpr.25\textwidth-4mm\relax}

\newcommand\linefill{\leavevmode
    \rule{\wcolone}{0.4pt}\hspace*{4mm}\rule{.50\textwidth}{0.4pt}\hspace*{4mm}\rule{\dimexpr.25\textwidth-4mm\relax}{0.4pt}}

\makeatletter
\def\fillwithlines#1{%
  \begingroup
  \ifhmode
    \par
  \fi
  \hrule height 0pt
  \nobreak
  \cleaders\hbox to \hsize{\hskip \@totalleftmargin
          \vrule height \linefillheight depth 0pt width 0pt
          \linefill} \vskip #1 \hbox{}%
  \endgroup}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[c][1cm][t]{\textwidth}
\section{Sign on sheet}
\parbox{\dimexpr\wcolone+4mm\relax}{\textbf{Date}}%
\parbox{\dimexpr\wcoltwo+4mm\relax}{\textbf{Name}}%
\parbox{\wcolthree}{\textbf{Signature}}
\end{minipage}

\fillwithlines{\dimexpr\textheight-1cm\relax}

\end{document}
```

[image]