# Text under a line

Tags: formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [dynamic signature/date line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48152/dynamic-signature-date-line)

How can I make text under line in a form like this:

```
____________________
    name, phone
```

Or

```
Name:____________________
         (full name)
```

Thanks!

update:

Solution that two users provided works well for fixed-size `hspace`. It is also easy to make a function from it.

```
Name: $\underset{\text{(full name)}}{\underline{\hspace{5cm}}}$
```

However I am wondering if it is possible to use kind of dynamic `hspace`? Or it is completely different issue?

Comment: Solution which Martin posted here is not present in question you provided

Comment: True, it is not *exactly* the same (minor formatting and alignment), but it is similar in nature, hence the suggestive duplicate. It might be different if you had referenced that (or a similar question) with a specific difference to it saying why the solutions proposed is insufficient, or where you got stuck with reformatting it suit your needs.

Comment: Actually I still have troubles, trying to figure out in comments. Will update my question.

Comment: You can create a function of this: `\newcommand*{\fullname}[1][5cm]{$\underset{\text{(full name)}}{\underline{\hspace*{\dimexpr#1}}}$}` and then use `\fullname`, or `\fullname[7cm]` or `\fullname[2in]`, or `\fullname[1cm+3in]`. Note the optional/square brackets. Default, without brackets, is `5cm`.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know if its possible to say like `width: 100%` in html. I mean, how can I tell latex to stretch line from its origin point to document's right margin? Because I don't know how long it should be in cm (I have several fields one by one and they all starts with phrase of different length, like 'name' or 'phone number' and so on).

Comment: @dig, look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a solution based on (a probably abused) math mode. I defined a new command called `\tline` to make it more straightforward. The first argument is the text that you want underneath the line and the second argument is the length of the line that you want.

**Code/Example:**

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{amsmath}

% THIS IS MY NEWLY DEFINED COMMAND
\newcommand\tline[2]{$\underset{\text{#1}}{\text{\underline{\hspace{#2}}}}$}

\begin{document}

Name: \tline{(full name)}{1in}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image: sample output]

**Edit:** I modified the code so that the underline will fill the rest of the line. The technique was based off of [this](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=10246) answer to another question.

**Additional Preamble Code:**

```
% Code based on http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=10246
\newsavebox\mybox
\newlength\mylen
\newlength\fieldlen
\newcommand\tlinefill[2]{\noindent #1\sbox\mybox{#1}%
\settowidth\mylen{\usebox\mybox}%
\setlength\fieldlen{\linewidth}%
\addtolength\fieldlen{-\mylen}%
$\underset{\text{#2}}{\text{\underline{\hspace{\fieldlen}}}}$}
```

Using the new command `\tlinefill`, the line can fill the rest of the line. The first argument is the text that you want in front of the line and the second argument is the text that you want underneath the line. So, `\tlinefill{Name: }{(full name)}` will produce:

[image: more output]

Note that the `lipsum` text is there just to show the line width.

Comment: I just realized that Martin reached pretty much exactly the same solution that I did. The only difference is the definition of a command to make it easily reusable.

Comment: Yep actually looks similar. Is it possible to use kind of dynamic `hspace` so that it will grow to the right border of page?

Comment: @dig See my modified answer.

Answer (score 15):

Or a `\shortstack` that's lowered by `-\baselineskip` using `\raisebox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
How now \raisebox{-\baselineskip}{\shortstack{\underline{\hspace{3cm}}\\(brown cow)}}?
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Another possibility is to use `\underset` command from the amsmath package, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
$\underset{\text{name, phone}}{\underline{\hspace{5cm}}}$
\vspace*{2cm}

Name: $\underset{\text{(full name)}}{\underline{\hspace{5cm}}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make \hspace fill all available space from left to right?

Comment: For me this is the best solution because it doesn't break lines height like others.

Answer (score 6):

There are probably many ways to do this.  One would be to use a `tabular` environment:

```
\begin{tabular}{lc}
Name: & \underline{\hspace{2in}}\\
& \textsf{(full name)}
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a tabular environment

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
Name \begin{tabular}[t]{c}\hline \makebox[4cm][c]{(full name)} \\\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could also use a `minipage`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\TextLine}[2][5cm]{%
\begin{minipage}{#1}
    \par\noindent\hrule\smallskip
    \small \makebox[#1]{\textbf{#2}}
\end{minipage}
}
\begin{document}
    \TextLine{name, phone} 
​\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```