# How can I customize this code for signature line to fit a specific format?

Tags: macros, formatting

Found a nice piece of code here [Dynamic signature/date line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48152/dynamic-signature-date-line) and modified it to this:

```
\newcommand*{\DateAndSignature}[1]{%
..\newline
  \par\noindent\makebox[2.25in]{Musterstadt, den}{\hrulefill} \hfill\makebox[2.25in]{\hrulefill}%
  \par\noindent\makebox[2.25in][l]{} \hfill\makebox[2.25in][c]{#1}%
}%
```

But the result is not exactly as I would like it to be, which would be:

```
Musterstadt, den ______________      _______________________________
                                                Muster Name
```

The two parts shall be divided to left and right, as an extra, there might be an indentation to the usual paragraph width, but this is optional.

My problem is the line after *den*, can't get it there in a proper way - any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

combined solution, thanks to the given answers:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\newcommand*{\DateAndSignature}[1]{%
  \rule{0pt}{2\baselineskip} %
  \par\noindent\makebox[2.25in]{\indent Musterstadt, den \hrulefill} \hfill\makebox[2.25in]{\hrulefill}%
  \par\noindent\makebox[2.25in][l]{} \hfill\makebox[2.25in][c]{#1}%
}%

\begin{document}
\DateAndSignature{Muster Name}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Please post complete documents not just fragments that can't be run. I just moved a brace so the rule is in the fixed size box, which is I think what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\DateAndSignature}[1]{%
..\newline
  \par\noindent\makebox[2.25in]{Musterstadt, den \hrulefill} \hfill\makebox[2.25in]{\hrulefill}%
  \par\noindent\makebox[2.25in][l]{} \hfill\makebox[2.25in][c]{#1}%
}%


\begin{document}


\DateAndSignature{Muster Name}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This will use the full line width. Adjust the fractions of `\columnwidth` and the invisible rule for "vertical spacing" to suit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*{\DateAndSignature}[1]{%
  \par\nobreak\noindent
  \makebox[.55\columnwidth]{%
  \indent % comment out this line if you don't want the normal indentation
    \rule{0pt}{2\baselineskip}% vertical spacing
    Musterstadt, den \hrulefill}%
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}\makebox[.42\columnwidth]{\hrulefill}\\#1\end{tabular}\par
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\DateAndSignature{Muster name}

\end{document}
```

`lipsum` is just to show the result.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the alternative! Wish I could split the accept, but Davids attempt is the easiest way to adapt the code, however I used some of your parts to improve the formatting.