# How to produce a period sequence

Tags: formatting, forms

I would like to create a document which has a sequence of periods like:

```
......................
Date
```

and

```
............................
Signature
```

Is there any way to do it without typing all the periods myself (maybe even a way which was made for this often seen typographical quirk)?

Comment: Related: [Dynamic signature/date line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48152/5764)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`\dotfill`](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/spacebox.htm#hfill):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{multicol}

\NewDocumentCommand \dotbox {o O{.5\linewidth} m O{3ex} O{\linewidth}}
{
  \begin{minipage}{#2}
    \IfValueTF{#1}{#1}{\null}
    \\[#4]
    \makebox[#5]{\dotfill}
    \\
    #3
  \end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}
\hrule
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \dotbox[Please sign below:]{A. U. Thor}

  \dotbox[And your initials:]{A. U. T.}[6ex][6em]
\end{multicols}
\hrule
\vspace*{3cm}
\hrule
\dotbox[Sign here (4ex)][4cm]{\TeX.SX}[4ex]
\hspace*{2cm}
\dotbox[And here (3ex)][3cm]{\TeX.SX}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note that while this implementation allows you to have successive calls to `\dotbox` without a paragraph break, the baseline may be screwed up if you do so with differing dimensions, as can be seen from the second two uses.

Comment: how would I place 2 dotboxes on the same height?

Comment: I would use `multicol`; I haven't tried it, but I think it'd work.

Comment: @TheChymera See my edit.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a sample TeX file to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\mydots#1{\hbox to #1{\leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern 1mu\hbox{.}\mkern 1mu$}\hfil}}
\makeatother    

\mydots{5pc}

\end{document}
```

`\mydot{5pc}` will put dots for a width **5pc**. You can customize this.

Note: There is also a package named [`dashrule`](http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/dashrule/dashrule.pdf) which has so may features.

Comment: FYI, you missed the `\makeatother`

Comment: @SeanAllred: I don't think `\makeatother` is a must. You can check by giving `@@@` later in the text.

Comment: Put `\@ifundefined{fakemacro}{Should I be able to do this?}{I think not.}` right after `\mydots`.  Writing `@@@` is just like writing `aaa` or `bbb` as far as catcodes are concerned once you say `\makeatletter`; `@` is used for internal macros and should not be generally available at the document level.

Comment: your example is great - and dashrule is indeed even better. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Using `\hbox` is not really recommended, because it can have unexpected effects.

```
\newcommand{\dottedline}[3][3ex]{%
  \par % end the current paragraph (if necessary)
  \nopagebreak % don't break a page here
  \vspace{#1}% space before the signature
  \noindent\makebox[#2]{\dotfill}% make the dotted line
  \\* % go to a new line without any page break
  \noindent#3% signature
  \par % end the paragraph
}
```

Here's a complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\dottedline}[3][3ex]{%
  \par % end the current paragraph (if necessary)
  \nopagebreak % don't break a page here
  \vspace{#1}% space before the signature
  \noindent\makebox[#2]{\dotfill}% make the dotted line
  \\* % go to a new line without any page break
  \noindent#3% signature
  \par % end the paragraph
  \vspace{#1}% space below the signature
}

\begin{document}

Please sign here:

\dottedline{6cm}{A. U. Thor}

And your initials:

\dottedline[1ex]{3cm}{A. U. T.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good point; and neither of the existing solutions prevent the pagebreak.