# How can I make a signature and a date bar in one line?

Tags: signatures, date

I am writing my senior design report and I am creating it using Overleaf-LaTeX. My issue is that I can't get the underscore to look like this[image: signature]

I am using underscores to manually do this, with no avail since Overleaf will not add more than one space between underscores. This is my first time using LaTeX, I apologize if this is extremely easy.

Comment: Use a rule like so `\rule{2in}{0.4pt}`. Here is a full sample code: `\parbox{2in}{\rule{2in}{0.4pt}\\ ``Advisor Name''\\Faculty Advisor}\hfill\parbox{2in}{\rule{1in}{0.4pt}\\ Date\\\mbox{}}`

Comment: If you really want to force multiple spaces, you can (ab)use `~`.  That is, `~~~~` gives four spaces.

Comment: We've had this before...

Comment: @Werner for instance your answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48157/90087  The only difference I can see is that the OP, by the posted image example, asked for thicker gray signature lines.

Answer (score 1):

Using @azetina above code, but adding some `xcolor` for the gray signature lines:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

    \parbox{2in}{{\color{gray}\rule{2in}{1pt}}\\%
    ``Advisor's Name''\\Faculty Advisor}\hfill\parbox{2in}%
{{\color{gray}\rule{1in}{1pt}}\\%
    Date\\\mbox{}} 

 \end{document}
```

[image]

If a different shade of gray is needed then after `\usepackage{xcolor}` put a rgb definition, for instance `\definecolor{gray}{RGB}{192,192,192}` will give this result:

[image]

Comment: Note that how you defined the color setting you don't the `\color{black}` for the text.

Comment: I tried taking that out, and it made the undertext gray. I figure that if I had grouped things correctly I probably would not need the `\color{black}` .

Comment: @azetina took your advice and re-grouped so that the `\color{black}` control sequences are not needed.

Comment: @azetina and thanks for editing out the superfluous brackets.

Comment: That is why we are here to help each other. Note that the `{}` holds and ends the color statement, hence, we can make the suggested edit I did :)