# How to make a signature line aligned to the left?

Tags: graphics

I have researched and seen this type of question asked here before, but I was not able to figure out how to modify the solutions I saw there.

This is what I currently have:

[image]

I would like the line, and "Dr. Hill" to be aligned on the left, and I'm not sure but I think I would like the name a little closer to the line. This The current code I have is

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0in}p{2in}@{}}

& \rule{4cm}{0.4pt} \\
& Dr. Hill\\

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I have tried to put it into a `flushleft` environment, but that seemed not to affect it at all.

Sorry I did not know what to tag this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is the reason for the 0width first column?

Comment: @Bernard Thanks! I'm not familiar with the "tabular environment," so I just copied that and changed numbers around. A positive width seems to shift the line to the right, and 0 does what is shown. I tried negative, but that wasn't any better than 0.

Comment: It's simpler to remove it and use `\noindent` just before the tabular environment.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48152/dynamic-signature-date-line/501036

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick to your tabular environment, simply remove the first (empty) column that is causing the unwanted indentation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\begin{document}
Signature

\begin{tabular}{@{}p{2in}}
\rule{4cm}{0.4pt} \\
Dr. Hill\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

If you want to decrease the vertical distance between the line and the name, you can use the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\begin{document}
Signature

\begin{spacing}{1}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{2in}} 
\rule{4cm}{0.4pt} \\
Dr. Hill\\
\end{tabular}
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I would upvote but I don't have enough reputation.