# how to create a table that repeats in every page with fixed size?

Tags: spacing, margins, line, times, roman

https://ibb.co/zH7L8kj
[image: Table]

I've uploaded the image, I have this table to be repeated for 30 pages
the size is fixed as well.

The page should have margins of 2.5 cm from the left/right and 2 cm on top/bottom.
Times New Roman 12pt font should be used, with 1.0 line spacing.
Page numbers should be centered on the bottom of each page, outside of the table right on the bottom center.

Thanks advanced.

Edit:

Thanks to a fellow I have added some more details:

- Do you have a code?
  I don't know how to construct it
- What should be the content of the table?
  The content of the table would be reports written day by day include images
- Are there text to be added in parts of table as date or name of the writer?
  Yeah and the center is where the report goes/
- Paper size would be A4
- Is this something you want to print out and fill out by hand?
  No I'll write and add pictures in the larger center section of it for 30-40 pages
- Or do you want to fill the table in LaTeX as well?
  Yes
- If so, do you need automatic page breaks (because the content for one "work" is too large for one page) or is every page an independent unit?

  Yes every page is independent but the numbering should be in place an counting it

I hope I can find answers

Edit:
I know I'm new here. I'm willing to learn and would be happy to be welcomed here. I'm taking the advises and make my question more clear. Thanks for the comments

Comment: @close-voters: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or **vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close.**

Comment: Is this something you want to print out and fill out by hand? Or do you want to fill the table in LaTeX as well? If so, do you need automatic page breaks (because the content for one "work" is too large for one page) or is every page an independent unit? Please make your question as specific as you can, as you can see, we need to use a lot of effort to find out what exactly you need. Also, this question is quite broad. It would be much more useful if you could for example create a table that basically is what you want and then ask how to replicate that on every page.

Comment: @schtandard  Is this something you want to print out and fill out by hand? /// no I'll write and add pictures in the larger center section of it for 30-40 pages //// Or do you want to fill the table in LaTeX as well? ///// Yes //////  If so, do you need automatic page breaks (because the content for one "work" is too large for one page) or is every page an independent unit?///// Yes every page is independent but the numbering should be in place an counting it /////

Comment: Ok, finally: Do you insist on the rather cumbersome design in your image or can it be different as long as functionally equivalent?

Comment: @schtandard Equivalent it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just create an environment that makes the page for you.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
  \newcommand*\signaturelinewidth{5cm}
  \newcommand*\signaturelineheight{.4pt}
  \newcommand*\signaturelineraise{.4ex}
  \newcommand*\signaturelabelindent{.5cm}
  \newcommand*\signaturetextindent{}
  \NewDocumentCommand\signatureline{
    O{\signaturelinewidth}      % line width
    O{\signaturelabelindent}    % label margin
    O{%                           text indentation
      \ifx\@empty\signaturetextindent
        .5\dimexpr #2\relax
      \else
        \signaturetextindent
      \fi
    }
    m                           % label
    O{\signaturelineheight}     % line height
    O{\signaturelineraise}      % line raise
    D||{}                       % text
  }{%
    \parbox[t]{#1}{%
      \leftskip #3%
      \mbox{\strut #7}%
      \vskip -#6%
      \hrule height #5%
      \vskip #6%
      \scriptsize
      \leftskip #2%
      \rightskip #2%
      \strut #4%
    }%
  }
\makeatother

\NewDocumentEnvironment{edypage}{ m m m } {%
  \clearpage\noindent
  \begin{minipage}[t][.05\textheight]{\textwidth}%
    \begin{minipage}{.7\linewidth}%
      \sffamily\bfseries
      #2%
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{.15\linewidth}%
      \flushright
      #1%
    \end{minipage}%
    \vfil
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
      #3%
    \end{minipage}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \vfill\hrule\vfill\vfill\noindent
  \begin{minipage}[t][.75\textheight]{\textwidth}%
}{%
  \end{minipage}%
  \vfill\vfill\vfill\vfill\hrule\vfill\noindent
  \begin{minipage}[b][.1\textheight]{\textwidth}%
    \centering
    Approved%
    \vfil\vfil
    \signatureline{Student}%
    \hfil
    \signatureline{Company Authority}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \clearpage
}

\begin{document}

\begin{edypage}{24.07.2019}{A page for edy}{Implemented by the \texttt{tex.stackexchange.org} community}
  Here, you can write whatever.
\end{edypage}

\begin{edypage}{24.07.2091}{Another page for edy}{Implemented by The Future}
  You will have written something here.
\end{edypage}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

- If you do not like this design or if it does not fit your need entirely, you can easily make you own following the same idea: Make an environment that creates a page for you. Make sure to call `\clearpage` before and after to make sure that there really isn't anything else on the page.
- If you just want to change some lengths, go ahead. This should not break as long as the widths (heights) of `minipage`s next to (above) each other add up to less than `\textwidth` (`\textheight`).
- I did not bother with page margins, fonts or font size. Those details are separate from the main idea and you can find many questions dealing with them on this site.
- The macro for the signature lines is from my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501036/48973).